# RESTful URI design to perform an update operation on a field that is not included the request body?

Tags: rest, request, uri, httpresponse

I'm trying to build a simple Email Verification API. Below you can find the expected client requests in order:

- The client gets an `email address` as an input. (e.g. mail@example.com)
- The client sends a request: `GET /emails/?email=mail@example.com`
- If `mail@example.com` has not been created before, meaning the previous request returns an empty list as a response, it sends a request: `POST /emails/` where `email@example.com` is in the request body parameters.
- The client sends a request: `POST /email-verifications/` with `email_id` in the request body and creates a new email verification object. Upon successful creation, the client receives a token in the response body and 6-digit verification code is sent to the corresponding email address.
- Now the client gets `verification code` as an input from the user.
- The client sends a request: `PATCH /email-verifications/id/` with `token` and `code` in the request body.

I'm not exactly sure about the last step since the corresponding update operation receives two inputs as `token` and `code` that won't be updated in the instance. Rather, they will be compared with the existing instance and upon success another field `is_verified` will be updated.

Is this a right way to implement such operation? Or are there any better practices that I can follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PATCH` is often not the perfect fit for things, and I think that you probably also shouldn't be using it here.

We've ran into a similar issue as you did and wondered how to design it. In our example it wasn't a `token` and `code` but it was an API for changing a users password.

Also in our case, a client would send a new password to a server but the server would never return the password.

The most appropriate solution for us ended up being a special `password` resource, with a url like:

```
/users/x/password
```

A `GET` request on this url would always yield a 403, and only a `PUT` request will be supported here. I kinda have the feeling that your design problem should be solved the same way.

Comment: I've ended up with a similar approach and didn't use PATCH as a method type. Instead I've used POST /email-verifications/<pk>/confirmation/. Seems more intuitive. Thanks!